# Finding groups of connected users from dataset

Tags: r, feature-extraction

Currently I am working on implementing "relation extraction" function from datasets with given structure:

```
Name1  Name2
Bob    Tom
Mike   Bob
Denise John
Kate   Bob
John   Kate
Mike   Tom
Mark   Denise
Denise Kate
Tom    John
```

Both columns are "character" type, basically datasets holds information that user with "Name1" knows user with "Name2" (symmetric relation). 
What I am trying to do is find groups of users in which "everyone knows everyone" (I am not sure how they are called in english, my lecturer calls them "super groups"). The output of that function should contain list of extracted groups and list of members of each group. So for the example dataset above it would be (group is considered "valid" when it has 3 or more members) :

```
Group 1: Bob Tom Mike
Group 2: Denise John Kate
```

Format really doesn't matter that much, it just need to contain that kind of information. Now, I actually implemented function that works, but execution time is extremely long (for dataset with ~550 000 rows it took about 9 hours) - what I did was basically creating subsets of friends for every relation, so for relation Bob - Tom from example data it would look like this:

```
Subset 1:
Name1  Name2
Bob Mike
Bob Kate

Subset 2:
Name1  Name2
Tom Mike
Tom John
```

And then I checked if users from column "Name2" from 1st subset appear in same column in 2nd subset etc... I know this method is far from optimal and I am not surprised at all that it takes so long to execute that function. I was wondering if someone could propose better solution to this problem (I don't even need code, just maybe link to some algorithm or explanation how to do that kind of "group extraction" in optimal way).

Comment: Look at the igraph package. Graph theory is the standard tool for what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like cliques in graph theory. First, we load your sample data

```
dd <- read.table(text="Name1  Name2
Bob    Tom
Mike   Bob
Denise John
Kate   Bob
John   Kate
Mike   Tom
Mark   Denise
Denise Kate
Tom    John", header=T)
```

Then turn it into a proper graph

```
gg <- graph_from_data_frame(dd, directed=F)
plot(gg)
```

[image]

You can then find cliquies with at least three members

```
cliques(gg, min=3)
# [[1]]
# + 3/7 vertices, named:
# [1] Bob  Mike Tom 
# 
# [[2]]
# + 3/7 vertices, named:
# [1] Denise Kate   John
```

Answer (score 0):

As Frank has commented, you are describing a typical Graph Theory problem.

A graph is a structure that has Nodes (in your case people) and Edges between some of these nodes (in your case friendship relationships).

There is in fact a word for the "super groups" that you are looking for: A subset of nodes where each node is connected to each other node in that subset is called a *clique* or a *fully connected subgraph*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) In particular you seem to be interested in all cliques that have cardinality 3 or greater.

The good news is that finding all cliques is a well-known problem in Graph Theory (The [Clique Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)) and implementations in packages exist (see below). The bad news is that it is known to be NP-complete. Therefore, depending on the size and topology graph, even the best implementations may take quite some time. The article above provides some further information on this.

The `igraph` package in R provides a `cliques` function that will find these cliques for you, once you have loaded your data as a graph structure. As in your case you have a list of existing relationships, I suggest you look at the `graph_from_edgelist` function in that package.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating cohesive blocks can give you some insights:

```
library(igraph)
camp <- graph_from_literal(Bob -Tom,
                           Mike -Bob,
                           Denise -John,
                           Kate - Bob,
                           John - Kate,
                           Mike - Tom,
                           Mark - Denise,
                           Denise - Kate,
                           Tom - John)
campBlocks <- cohesive_blocks(camp)
campBlocks
plot(campBlocks, camp, vertex.label=V(camp)$name, margin=-0.2,
     vertex.shape="rectangle", vertex.size=24, vertex.size2=8,
     mark.border=1, colbar=c(NA, NA,"green","orange") )
```

[image]

Cohesive blocking determines the hierarchical subsets of graph vertices based on their structural cohesion.  Moreover, you can use the following to see your desired subgraphs

```
largest_cliques(camp)
```

output:

```
3/7 vertices, named:
[1] John   Denise Kate  

[[2]]
  3/7 vertices, named:
[1] Bob  Tom  Mike
```